# C# console App compare records to database

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, console-application

I am parsing a flat file which is working line by line and inserting into the database but I want to add an additional step, actually additional 2 steps.

First I only want records for recalls for specific car manufacturers which I have a database table called AutoMake that has a list of all the makes I want to include. I need to compare the record to that table to ensure that it is a record of one of the makes that I want to include.

Then I need to do a second check to make sure the record is not already in my database.
This is a console App and I am using Entity for this. So here is my code I am driving myself crazy trying to write and rewrite this to include the checks but im just not getting it.

Oh and not that it really matters because if someone can get me in the right direction I can move from there but `tokens[2]` is the `MAKETXT` and `RCL_CMPT_ID` is `tokens[23]` and `RCL_CMPT_ID` can be used to verify if a record is already in the database since it is a unique value

```
    public static void ParseTSV(string location)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing.....");

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(location))
        {
            var lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });

            if (lines.Length > 0)
            {
               foreach (string line in lines)
               {
                  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                  {
                    continue;
                  }
                  var tokens = line.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                  var recalls = new Recalls();

                  recalls.RECORD_ID = tokens[0];
                  recalls.CAMPNO = tokens[1];
                  recalls.MAKETXT = tokens[2];
                  recalls.MODELTXT = tokens[3];
                  recalls.YEARTXT = tokens[4];
                  recalls.MFGCAMPNO = tokens[5];
                  recalls.COMPNAME = tokens[6];
                  recalls.MFGNAME = tokens[7];
                  recalls.BGMAN = tokens[8];
                  recalls.ENDMAN = tokens[9];
                  recalls.RCLTYPECD = tokens[10];
                  recalls.POTAFF = tokens[11];
                  recalls.ODATE = tokens[12];
                  recalls.INFLUENCED_BY = tokens[13];
                  recalls.MFGTXT = tokens[14];
                  recalls.RCDATE = tokens[15];
                  recalls.DATEA = tokens[16];
                  recalls.RPNO = tokens[17];
                  recalls.FMVSS = tokens[18];
                  recalls.DESC_DEFECT = tokens[19];
                  recalls.CONEQUENCE_DEFECT = tokens[20];
                  recalls.CORRECTIVE_ACTION = tokens[21];
                  recalls.NOTES = tokens[22];
                  recalls.RCL_CMPT_ID = tokens[23];


                  string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
                  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                  {
                      SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(GetInsertSqlCust(recalls), connection);
                      connection.Open();
                      cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      connection.Close();
                      cmdIns.Dispose();
                      cmdIns = null;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:Get the ID to check against
2:Get the table where the search needs to be done like

```
 string strExpression="";
    (Datatable tdGeneric = dal.getsometable())
```

3:To check the auto make if exists:

```
if ( tdGeneric != null && tdGeneric.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
   strExpression = "tablecolumnsname = '" + recalls.MAKETXT + "' ";
   tdGeneric.DefaultView.RowFilter = strExpression;
   tdGeneric = tdGeneric.DefaultView.ToTable();
    if (tdGeneric.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
          //make exist
    }
    else
     make don't exists

  }
  else
 {
   make don't exist skip that text file's record
 }
```

4: if make exist then check for a record if that exists in a table.

get the original table,search on that table for specific id in your case:

```
 (Datatable tdGeneric2 = dal.getsometable())
 if ( tdGeneric2 != null && tdGeneric.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
       strExpression = "tablecolumnsname = '" + recalls.RCL_CMPT_ID + "' ";
       tdGeneric2.DefaultView.RowFilter = strExpression;
       tdGeneric2 = tdGeneric2.DefaultView.ToTable();
          if (tdGeneric2.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
              //record exist
        }
        else
         record don't exists
      }
      else
     {
       record don't exist insert the record, or some flag to insert a record
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantages of caching. Fetch all the Makes before reading the file and do a lookup in the List or Dictionary of existing AutoMakes to check if the AutoMake already exists in database or it is a new one. If the AutoMake is new, insert the record in database and also add the make in List\Dictionary. If AutoMake already exists, skip the line and move to next line.